# Redundant facet and axis labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet

I have two questions regarding axis and facet labels in ggplot. I have searched around but failed to find exactly what I wanted.

I am using dotplots to graph treatment effects and confidence intervals for an electoral dataset featuring several sample disaggregation criteria (ie: coalition, office 
and (discontinuity). The data, and code for the plot follow:

```
treatment<- c(0.0575991,  0.0679221,    0.4750282,  0.5264731,  0.649701,   0.4012088,  0.8792834,  0.7785651,  -0.0523253, 0.302815,   0.0200715,  1.12161,    0.2174055,  -0.7917859, 0.053338,   -0.8650882, 0.060367,   0.0688683,  0.4708295,  0.5074752,  0.3618211,  0.2811037,  0.7121391,  0.3285163,  -0.1002695, 0.4352929,  -0.1790575, 0.7706336,  0.2003012,  0.5434131,  -0.0008607, 0.5872229)

window <-   c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5,    2.5,    2.5,    2.5,    2.5,    2.5,    2.5,    2.5,    2.5,    2.5,    2.5,    2.5,    2.5,    2.5,    5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5)

office <-  c("Local Council",   "Local Council",    "Local Council",    "Local Council",    "Lower Chamber",    "Lower Chamber","Lower Chamber",    "Lower Chamber",    "Mayor",    "Mayor",    "Mayor",    "Mayor",    "Senate",   "Senate",   "Senate",   "Senate",   "Local Council",    "Local Council",    "Local Council",    "Local Council",    "Lower Chamber",    "Lower Chamber",    "Lower Chamber",    "Lower Chamber",    "Mayor",    "Mayor",    "Mayor",    "Mayor",    "Senate",   "Senate",   "Senate",   "Senate")

coalition   <-  c(1,    2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  2)

upper   <-  c(0.0775991,    0.0879221,  0.5550282,  0.6464731,  0.909701,   0.9412088,  1.2792834,  1.4185651,  0.2276747,  0.602815,   0.4400715,  2.26161,    2.9374055,  5.2482141,  2.013338,   9.4549118,  0.060367,   0.0888683,  0.5508295,  0.6074752,  0.6018211,  0.6011037,  0.9921391,  0.8285163,  0.5197305,  0.7552929,  6.4009425,  1.4106336,  0.8203012,  1.8034131,  0.7791393,  1.8072229)

lower   <-  c(0.0375991,    0.0479221,  0.3950282,  0.4064731,  0.389701,   -0.1387912, 0.4792834,  0.1385651,  -0.3323253, 0.00281500000000001,    -0.3999285, -0.0183899999999999,    -2.5025945, -6.8317859, -1.906662,  -11.1850882,    0.060367,   0.0488683,  0.3908295,  0.4074752,  0.1218211,  -0.0388963, 0.4321391,  -0.1714837, -0.7202695, 0.1152929,  -6.7590575, 0.1306336,  -0.4196988, -0.7165869, -0.7808607, -0.6327771)

df <- data.frame(treatment, as.factor(window),office, coalition, upper, lower)

ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = as.factor(window), y= treatment))+geom_pointrange( data = df,  stat = "identity",
mapping = aes(ymin= lower,ymax=upper))+facet_wrap(coalition ~ office, ncol=4, scales = "free")
```

where the midpoint of the dotplot captures the "treatment" vector" and
"upper" and "lower" give the upper and lower limits of the segments depicting confidence intervals.
I am using ggplot and exploiting facet_wrap to disaggregate results by coalition (coded "1"
and "2") and office .

My questions are:

1- How could I avoid redundancy in the labels so that the numbers 1 and 2 labelling coalitions could span across the four columns in each row?

2- How could I avoud redundancy in x-axis labels? (ie: to show axis labels only once
for each column)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Luis

Answer (score 3):

Just replace `facet_wrap` with `facet_grid` and delete the `ncol` argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zarat. I initially tried with facet_grid which indeed addressed this issue. But I had to change to facet_wrap because facet_grid did not allow me to set individual y scales for each facet. That is very critical because the range of y values across facets. Do you know any way of reconciling this two goals?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have a solution for this either.